# Why does Amazon S3 automatically allow permissions to all objects in my bucket? How can I deny permissions to all objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an amazon S3 bucket used with Cloudfront so that I can control access to the objects in my bucket.  I want to restrict access to all objects in my bucket, however if I set the permissions to my bucket so that only the admin and my Cloudfront origin ID are granted permissions, all my objects within my bucket still all include permissions for 'Everyone'. What can I do to fix this? I am new to AWS, and I have been using [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) as a resource for how to serve private content along with [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html), but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. If I manually select each object within my bucket I can remove permissions one by one, but seeing how I use it for both static and media files and have close to 1000 objects, I can't manually update permissions for each object individually.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the files to be visible through CloudFront, why do you want to restrict if through S3?

Comment: My site allows users to upload video, then I use ffmpeg to convert the video to flv, and flowplayer for http streaming. Videos are pay per view for a niche market, requiring the need to restrict access to some of the content in s3.  This is my first time working with ffmpeg, heroku (which is where I host my site), anything AWS, and any sort of production environment whatsoever, and I am finding it hard to get information on how to do this. As far as I'm aware, S3 and Cloudfront is how to do it. I'm also having trouble with ffmpeg uploading the converted content to S3, and unsure of what to do.

Comment: Check out AWS new transcoding service: http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/

Comment: Thanks. I looked into it, but the pricing seems to be a little ridiculous in my opinion for what I need.